# Generic function works, but generic class doesn't?

Tags: reflection, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I would like a class that is a generic for `KProperty1`, I can do this for a function, but not a class:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty1

data class Dog(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun <P: KProperty1<*, *>> reflectionHelper(input: P) = input.name

fun <P: KProperty1<*, *>> getReflectionHelper(clazz: P) = ReflectionHelper<P>()

class ReflectionHelper<P: KProperty1<*, *>> {
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    println(reflectionHelper(Dog::age))  // Works
    val helper1 = getReflectionHelper(Dog::age)  // Also Works
    val helper2 = ReflectionHelper<Dog::age>()  // Error: Type inference failed
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dog::age` is a value (of type `KProperty1<Dog, String>`), not a type. In between `<` and `>` you need to put a type, or you need to omit them entirely and the type will be inferred (that's what happens in the first two lines).

So the equivalent to your `fun`s would be

```
class ReflectionHelper<P: KProperty1<*, *>>(input: P) { ... }
val helper2 = ReflectionHelper(Dog::age)
```

If you don't need `input: P` as a parameter, you'll have to specify `P` explicitly both for `fun` and for `class`.